# Probabilities of at least one head with a (very) unfair coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> I have a large pool of DNA molecules. A few carry a mutation, but most
> do not. For each DNA molecule,
>
> $$P(\text{mutated}) = 0.0003$$
>
> $$P(\text{normal}) = 0.9997$$
>
> I am drawing $300$ of those DNA molecules. What is the probability
> that I take at least one mutated?

My logic is that this is like flipping a (very) unfair coin $300$ times, where $P(\text{heads}) = 0.0003$ and $P(\text{tails}) = 0.997$. So what is the probability of getting at least one head (mutation)? This is equal to the probability of *not* getting all tails (normal).

There are only two possibilities: I get all tails (normal), or I do not. So we have the probability of getting at least one mutation is:

$= 1 - P(\text{all normal})$

$= 1 - P(\text{normal}) \cdot P(\text{normal}) \cdot P(\text{normal}) \cdots \text{($300$ times)}$

$= 1 - P(\text{normal}) ^ {300} $

$= 1 - 0.91$

$= 0.09$

Hence, there is a $9\%$ chance of getting at least one mutation.

---

Now, there are only a few options: I can have exactly $1$ mutation, or I can have exactly $2$ mutations, etc. My intuition tells me that summing the probabilities for all these options should give the same result, i.e., the probability of getting exactly $1$ mutation $+$ the probability of getting exactly $2$ mutations $+ \cdots$ should give $0.09$.

Probability of getting exactly $1$ mutated

$=P(\text{mutated}) \cdot P(\text{normal}) \cdot P(\text{normal}) \cdot \cdots \cdot P(\text{normal}) \quad \text{($299$ normal occurrences)}$

$= P(\text{mutated}) \cdot P(\text{normal})^{299}$

$= 0.0003 \cdot (0.9997)^{299}$

$= 0.00027$

So the logic seems to be:

$$\text{Probability of getting exactly $n$ mutated} = P(\text{mutated})^n * P(\text{normal})^{300-n}$$

With this formula, I can calculate the probability of getting exactly $2$ mutated, $3$ mutated, $4$ mutated, etc., until $300$. However, when I sum all these probabilities (done in R), I only get $0.000274$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try `dbinom(0:20, 300, 0.0003)` in R: the initial probability is your rounded `0.91` and the others are for positive numbers.  Together they add up to $1$ (all subject to rounding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great approach, but it has one error. You should take the positions of mutations into account. The value:
$$P(\text{mutated}) \cdot P(\text{normal})^{299}$$
is equal to the probability of having one mutation **at a specific position**. For instance, this is the probability of having one mutation **, which is at the first position**.

You must consider the number of positions where the mutation might appear to fix your formula. Here, it is obvious that there are $300$ possible positions for the mutation. In general, if you have $n$ mutations, the total number of ways to choose $n$ positions from a total of $m$ positions (here $m=300$)  is given by:
$${m \choose n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$$
These are known as binomial coefficients, and the above is read as '$m$ choose $n$'. You should read up on them!

The correct probability of $n$ mutations is hence given by:
$${300 \choose n}P(\text{mutated})^n \cdot P(\text{normal})^{300-n}$$
Here's a way you can make sense of this coefficient. Assume you have $$P(\text{mutated}) = P(\text{normal}) = 0.5$$ just like a coin toss. Your original formula would suggest that the probability of getting no heads and $150$ heads are equal, which is not true. We expect roughly half the tosses to land heads with high probability. This is because the coefficient ${300 \choose n}$ is highest when $n=150$.

Comment: Brilliant, that fixes it. Thanks @Haran.

For the record, I get

Probability of exactly 1 mutated (at any draw)

$ \frac{300!}{1! \;\ (300-1)!}\  * P(mutated)^1 * P(normal)^{300-1} = 300 * 0.0003 * 0.9997^{299} = 0.082 $

Probability of exactly 2 mutated (at any draws) $= 0.0037$

etc.

which will get me to $0.9$ eventually